# Fabric css styles not working in spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, fabric

I'm trying to use the fabric List component in an spfx webpart. 
The code below was taken directly from https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/list

```
return (
     <div >
      <div className='ms-ListItem is-unread is-selectable'>
      <span className='ms-ListItem-primaryText'>Title</span>
      <span className='ms-ListItem-tertiaryText'>Description</span>
    </div>

    )
```

The Title and description appear in exactly the same font. Is there something special I need to do to get the fabric css included in an spfx webpart?

I tried including

```
require('../../../node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.css');
```

but it made no difference

Comment: Needed to include require('../../../node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.component..css');

Comment: manually requiring the above broke the drop downs and some other components in my app. i ended up reverting that change, the css classes noted in my question are not included in the office ui fabric react css so they have no effect. i have no idea why. ended up using custom css.

Answer (score 0):

So,

What does F12 Network tab reveal?
Any Fabric trying to load?
And from what URI? (*I think you will see a 404 here*)

You can reference Fabric from the CDN:

//spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/7.0.0/css/fabric.min.css